# Perl: output array in a column

Tags: regex, perl, loops, csv, text

I was trying to grep string "Distance: " from "pairsAngles.txt" within each of over 2,000 subdirectories; the names of the subdirectories are obtained from a csv file.
However, the following code only give me a huge single line of output in csv format which I couldn't even open with an text editor:

```
my @pairs=qw();
my @result=();

my $in;
my $out;
my $pairs;
my $dist = "";
my $dir = "/home/avabelieve/aaPROJECT/helicalPair_ax/selectedPairs/renumberedPdb/clusterPairs-1.25-12-05_windows.12.resle3.2A.RMSD1.3/oligomerAngle";
my $cluster = "clst1.csv";
open ($in, $cluster) || die "cannot open \"$cluster\": $!";
my $cU = "clst1Updated.csv";
open ($out, ">$cU") || die "cannot open '$cU' $!";
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });

while (my $c1 = <$in>) {    
    chomp $c1;
    push @pairs, $c1;

    foreach $c1 (uniq @pairs) {
        find (\&Matches, "$dir/$c1");
            sub Matches {
                open ($pairs, "oligomerAngles.out") or die "$!";

                while (my $dist = <$pairs>) {

                if ($dist =~ m/Distance: /){                     

                    chomp $dist;
                    push (@result, "$dist\n");
                    @result = split ": ", $dist;
                        }               

                    } 
}               } chdir "..";

if (not $csv->eof) {
  $csv->error_diag();
}
$csv->print ($out, [uniq @pairs, @result]);
}
close $out or die "$!";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some odd reason, Text::CSV_XS defaults to having no end-of-line separator when generating a CSV. From the docs for [the eol attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#eol)...

> When [eol is] not passed in a generating instance, records are not terminated at all, so it is probably wise to pass something you expect. A safe choice for eol on output is either $/ or \r\n.

You can pass `eol => $/` to `Text::CSV_XS->new` (`$/` defaults to the newline appropriate for the current operating system) , or you can use [`$csv->say`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#say) instead of `$csv->print` which uses `$/` for its eol default. I'd recommend doing both.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked!!! But now I have another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148048/perl-redundancy-due-to-restart-in-foreach