# Perl: redundancy due to restart in foreach?

Tags: perl, loops, search, foreach

I was trying to grep string "Distance: " from "pairsAngles.txt" within each of over 2,000 subdirectories; the names of the subdirectories are obtained from a csv file. But for some reason foreach() restarts from the beginning every loop. So the output looks like this:
[image]
Apparently all the Distances are supposed to be in one column...

I'm not sure which step is causing the problem. 
Code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use Cwd qw(cwd);
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my @pairs=qw();
my @result=();

my $in;
my $out;
my $pairs;
my $dist = "";
my $dir = "/home/avabelieve/aaPROJECT/helicalPair_ax/selectedPairs/renumberedPdb/clusterPairs-1.25-12-05_windows.12.resle3.2A.RMSD1.3/oligomerAngle";

my $cluster = "clst1.csv";
open ($in, $cluster) || die "cannot open \"$cluster\": $!";

my $cU = "clst1Updated.csv";
open ($out, ">$cU") || die "cannot open '$cU' $!";

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/ });

while (my $c1 = <$in>) {    
    chomp $c1;
    push @pairs, $c1;

    foreach $c1 (uniq @pairs) {
        find (\&Matches, "$dir/$c1");
        sub Matches {
            open ($pairs, "pairsAngles.txt") or die "$!";

            while (my $dist = <$pairs>) {

                if ($dist =~ m/Distance: /) {                    

                    chomp $dist;
                    push (@result, "$dist\n");
                    @result = split "\t", $dist;
                }               

            } 
        }
    }
    chdir "..";

    if (not $csv->eof) {
        $csv->error_diag();
    }
    $csv->say ($out, [uniq @pairs, @result]);
}
close $out or die "$!";
```

Comment: You said "*foreach() restarts from the beginning every loop*"... the beginning of what? And the beginning of which loop? I think I know what you mean, but could you clarify?

Comment: The beginning of the csv file which contains all the subdirectory names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop adds to the list of `@pairs`.

```
while (my $c1 = <$in>) {    
    chomp $c1;
    push @pairs, $c1;
```

The `foreach` loop iterates over those pairs.

```
foreach $c1 (uniq @pairs) {
    find (\&Matches, "$dir/$c1");
```

Since the `foreach` loop is inside the `while` loop, every time a pair is added to `@pairs` the `foreach` loop will iterate over the ever growing `@pairs` all over again starting from the beginning.

To avoid this, finish building `@pairs` and then loop over it.

```
while (my $c1 = <$in>) {    
    chomp $c1;
    push @pairs, $c1;
}

foreach $c1 (uniq @pairs) {
    find (\&Matches, "$dir/$c1");
    ...
}
```

Incidentally, that `while` loop can be better written to take advantage of `chomp` working on a list.

```
my @pairs = <$in>;
chomp @pairs;
```

Comment: The change of while loop didn't really work... Also, now the output went back to oneline... See my 3rd question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149051/perl-output-still-only-one-line

Answer (score 1):

There are two puzzling places for me.

(1)  You add a line of input to `@pairs`, with `push @pairs, $c1`.  But then you process *all* (unique) pairs, every time. So your code is re-processing all previously processed pairs first, and adding that. Is that intended? It seems that this way you get repeated results. Instead, you can collect pairs, prune duplicates, then process.

```
my @pairs = uniq <$in>;  # chomp if needed, chomp(@pairs)
foreach $c1 (@pairs) { ... }
```

(2) The code adds `$dist` to `@result` -- but then it overwrites that by assigning to `@result`.

```
push (@result, "$dist\n");
@result = split "\t", $dist;
```

Again, is this intended?

Comment: Good point. It was definitely not intended... I was just trying to get all the subdirectory names (@pairs) from the input csv file and then do grep. Actually that "uniq" is not necessary here because all the subfolder names are unique; however I've been receiving duplicated results...

Comment: Ah, then drop the `uniq`, better yet.  Note that you may _not_ need to chomp either (depending on the processing).  The second point is also valid -- the code _does_ change `@result` twice, and in contradictory ways.  One of these is not needed.  The second one always overwrites the whole `@result`.

Comment: Thank you so much zdim! I wish the system allows me to give you a green check mark also...