# Perl: output still only one line

Tags: regex, perl, csv, text, format

This is the 3rd question on the same project: 
I was trying to grep string "Distance: " from "pairsAngles.txt" within each of over 2,000 subdirectories; the names of the subdirectories are obtained from a csv file.
After passing eol => $/ to Text::CSV_XS->new AND use $csv->say, the output is still one line...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my @pairs=();
my @result=();
my $c1;
my $in;
my $out;
my $pairs;
my $dist = "";
my $dir = "/home/avabelieve/aaPROJECT/helicalPair_ax/selectedPairs/renumberedPdb/clusterPairs-1.25-12-05_windows.12.resle3.2A.RMSD1.3/oligomerAngle";
my $cluster = "clst1.csv";
open ($in, $cluster) || die "cannot open \"$cluster\": $!";
my $cU = "clst1Updated.csv";
open ($out, ">$cU") || die "cannot open '$cU' $!";
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/ });

while ($c1 = <$in>) {
    chomp $c1;
    push @pairs, $c1;
}

foreach $c1 (@pairs) {
    find (\&Matches, "$dir/$c1");
    sub Matches {
        open ($pairs, "pairsAngles.txt") or die "$!";

        while (my $dist = <$pairs>) {

            if ($dist =~ m/Distance: /) {                    
                chomp $dist;
                push (@result, "$dist\n");
            }               

        } 
    }
}
chdir "..";

if (not $csv->eof) {
    $csv->error_diag();
} 

$csv->say ($out, [@pairs, @result]);
close $out or die "$!";
```

Comment: You may have noticed I keep editing your code to change the bracing and indentation. Where the braces and indentation go are very important to making code readable, and in particular to your question, to knowing what code is in what loop. Consider adapting this more commonly understood bracing style.

Comment: At this point it feels like you're moving code around until something works without fully understanding what's going on. And we don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, so there's only so much we can do to help. So why don't you explain what you're trying to accomplish here? Give us specific inputs, like some short CSV data, a small example directory tree, and what you expect as the output.

Comment: Here is what I see. You get directories in `@pairs`. For one file in each you fetch `$dist` and add it to `@results`. A guess: you want to write out a file with rows `directory | dist-line`.  The problem: what if `$dist` is found more than once or not found in a file?  Then `@pairs` and `@results` mismatch in length and it is not possible to simply write out the file. You'd have to add some processing in the loop that would associate multiple-or-zero matches with directory for which they happen.  If there can be only _one_ match, code is better written differently.  Is this making sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you want to combine `@pairs` and `@result` in your output, but to write out the whole array into a spreadsheet you need, per synopsis in [Text::CSV_XS docs](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.23/CSV_XS.pm)

```
 $csv->say ($fh, $_) for @rows;
```

Let us know how `@pairs` and `@result` should be paired in output for more detail.

---

A clarification: the written rows should have a cell for directory and another for the corresponding matching line, and we know for sure that there is exactly one such match in each file.  Then

```
if (@pairs != @result) {
    die "Mismatching lengths: directory " . scalar(@pairs) .
        " vs matches " . scalar(@result);
}
for my $i (0..$#pairs) {
    $csv->say($out, [$pairs[$i], $result[$i]]);
}
```

Please note that `@pairs != @result` does *not* guard against all possible unexpected mismatches, it is more of a hint to include stricter checking in the code.  (There could be a no-match in one file but two in another and arrays would end up having the same length, for example.)  A check where `@result` is added to would test that there was indeed exactly one match.

---

A note. The code at one place removes the new line with `chomp` but then puts it back, `\n`.

```
chomp $dist;
push (@result, "$dist\n");
```

The `\n` is not needed and then `""` are not needed either -- just `push @result, $dist;`. As for the newline, either remove it with `chomp` or leave it (remove `chomp`). I don't see why a newline would be needed on a string that goes into a spreadsheet.

Comment: I just need two columns in the final csv output: first column contains all the subdirectory names from `@pairs` and the second contains distances from `@results`... Am I mistaken in my approach?

Comment: @AvaXue OK, thank you.  Please see my comment below your question --  can you have more than one match `$dist`  in a file, or is possible to have none?  If a file has more than one `$dist` line, how do you want to have that in the spreadsheet?  In that row you'd have a cell with the directory name and then ... where do multiple `$dist` go? Or do you want a row for each, even for the same directory? If there can be only one such line per file, are you _sure_ of that?  I am not sure I am explaining this well -- do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure there's always only one match `$dist` in each pairsAngles.txt under each subdirectory.

Comment: @AvaXue Alright.  If you are "_pretty sure_" then it's easy, I'll add it shortly.  I am being careful because if an extra (or missing) one somehow sneaks in, using two arrays and assuming equal lengths can lead to bad behavior. I'll add a test for that.

Comment: From linux terimnal: 
`Mismatching lengths of directory/match arrays  at ./test2.pl line 42, <$subdir> line 160.`
line 42: `csv->say($out, [$pairs[$i], $result[$i]]);`
The problem I think comes from either foreach or while...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111620/discussion-between-ava-xue-and-zdim).

Comment: @AvaXue  Added sizes of arrays in the `die` print

Comment: Thank you @zdim! I'd prefer to continue with the new question :)

Comment: @AvaXue  Very well :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `$csv->say` is at the end of the program, and it's not in a loop, it will only ever print one line. It will have every pair and every result.

```
$csv->say ($out, [@pairs, @result]);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you probably want to print your results inside a loop.