# Recursive subdirectory grep

Tags: perl, grep

I'm trying to grep the string `Distance:`  from each `pairsAngles.txt` file within over 2,000 subdirectories; the names of the subdirectories are obtained from a CSV file.

Each subdirectory contains one `pairsAngles.txt`, within which there is only one line that contains `Distance:` . However, my current `foreach` and `while` loops give me eight `Distance` values for each subdirectory.

In addition, each subsequent subdirectory gets all the distances from the previous subdirectories.

Like this:

[image]

A text version of the picture (row #4, column #2 has 4*8 = 32 entries of Distance)

All the `pairsAngles.txt` files are in subdirectories, and each subdirectory has a unique name.

I first read all the subdirectory names from the CSV file and split them into an array, then retrieve every element from that array to get into a subdirectory so that I can grep.

`clst1.csv` has only one column, which is the subfolder names:

```
oligomerAngle-1h2s-000_001-0003_0025_A-0034_0056_A-B004A012
oligomerAngle-5ax0-000_001-0010_0036_A-0042_0064_A-B004A013
oligomerAngle-4qnd-004_005-0046_0065_A-0069_0091_A-A004B006
oligomerAngle-2j8c-003_004-0171_0196_L-0226_0250_L-B011A001
```

```
oligomerAngle-2j8c-003_004-0171_0196_L-0226_0250_L-B011A001

Distance: 7.98675 
Distance: 7.98675 
Distance: 7.98675 
Distance: 7.98675 
Distance: 7.98675 
Distance: 7.98675 
Distance: 7.98675 
Distance: 7.98675
Distance: 7.95099 
Distance: 7.95099 
Distance: 7.95099 
Distance: 7.95099 
Distance: 7.95099 
Distance: 7.95099 
Distance: 7.95099
Distance: 7.95099
Distance: 7.87554 
Distance: 7.87554 
Distance: 7.87554 
Distance: 7.87554 
Distance: 7.87554 
Distance: 7.87554
Distance: 7.87554 
Distance: 7.87554 
Distance: 7.69417 
Distance: 7.69417 
Distance: 7.69417 
Distance: 7.69417 
Distance: 7.69417
Distance: 7.69417 
Distance: 7.69417 
Distance: 7.69417
```

But the actual value should just be "Distance: 7.69417"
Not sure what went wrong. Here's the code:

```
use File::Find;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my @pairs  = ();
my @result = ();
my $in;
my $out;
my $c1;
my $dist = "";
my $dir  = "/home/oligomerAngle";

my $cluster = "clst1.csv";
open( $in, $cluster ) || die "cannot open \"$cluster\": $!";

my $cU = "clst1Updated.csv";
open( $out, ">$cU" ) || die "cannot open '$cU' $!";

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/ } );

while ( $c1 = <$in> ) {
    chomp $c1;
    @pairs = split( ' ', $c1 );

    foreach my $pair (@pairs) {

        find( \&Matches, "$dir/$c1" );

        sub Matches {
            open( my $subdir, "pairsAngles.txt" ) or die "$!";

            while ( $dist = <$subdir> ) {

                if ( $dist =~ m/Distance:/ ) {
                    push( @result, "$dist" );
                }
            }
        }

        chdir "..";
        $csv->say( $out, [ "@pairs", "@result" ] );
    }
}

if ( not $csv->eof ) {
    $csv->error_diag();
}

close $out or die "$!";
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the actual text from your screenshot into the question? You should avoid screenshots of text because they're not searchable, they're not accessible to people with disabilities, and they force people to manually re-type your data to test it.

Comment: Inlining your sub in the middle of your code is dirty. Don't do that.

Comment: Schwern gave you such a nice hint on how to [indent code properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149051/perl-output-still-only-one-line#comment61836413_37149051). Please pay attention to it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks guys! Just made some changes based on the previous input.

Comment: `perltidy -pbp` is a pretty good start. And so very easy.

Comment: Thanks! Just cleaned it up with perltidy :)

Comment: Please can you show us what's in `clst1.csv`? You split each line into `@pairs` and then iterate over each element of that array, but you then do `find( \&Matches, "$dir/$c1" )` which is the same every time and independent of the value from the array. That can't be right. I'm also unclear why you're using `File::Find` if the locations of all the `pairsAngles.txt` files are in the clusters file

Comment: @Borodin All the pairsAngles.txt are in subdirectories, and each of the subdirectories has a unique name. I first read all the subdirectory names from the csv file and split them into an array, then retrieve every element from that array to get into a subdirectory so that I can grep. 
clst1.csv has only one column, which is the subfolder names:
oligomerAngle-1h2s-000_001-0003_0025_A-0034_0056_A-B004A012

oligomerAngle-5ax0-000_001-0010_0036_A-0042_0064_A-B004A013

oligomerAngle-4qnd-004_005-0046_0065_A-0069_0091_A-A004B006

oligomerAngle-2j8c-003_004-0171_0196_L-0226_0250_L-B011A001...

Comment: Does a line in `$cluster`, read with `while ( $c1 = <$in> )`, have:  (1) a name of a directory in which the file is, OR (2) a long string which has names of _subdirectories_, separated by spaces, where each of these _subdirectories_ has the file?

Comment: @zdim It has the full name of a subdirectory: 
oligomerAngle-3wu2-033_034-0004_0027_z-0034_0059_z-B010A004

Comment: And that's it?  Just that one string on the line, and the file is right inside of that subdirectory? So the exact path to your file is `$dir/oligomer.../pairsAngles.txt`, where `oligomer...` subdirectories are listed one per line in `$cluster`?

Comment: @zdim yes! Originally there were more columns and I used split to get that one column. Then I cleared up the file and made a separate csv file which only contains the names of the subdirectories.

Comment: Ah. It would've helped a lot having this information in the post, this now apears far simpler.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks @zdim for the persistent help :)

Comment: @AvaXue Removed my comment (about my edit) as it servers no purpose now, to clean up. (I'll remove this as well if you want to remove your response.)  Good to connect again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code seems to over-complicate the matters, given the clarifications.

The code below takes a subdirectory name from the `$cluster` file iterated over by `<$in>`, then it builds the file name using `$dir` and it.  Lines in the file are then iterated over to find the one with the pattern. Once that happens we print results and move on to the next file (in the next subdirectory).

Note that we don't really need `@result` unless more processing happens later.

```
# Iterate over subdirectories that each have the file
while ( $c1 = <$in> ) {
    chomp $c1;

    # Build the full file name in this subdirectory, open the file
    my $filename = "$dir/$c1/pairsAngles.txt";
    open my $fh_in, $filename  or die "$!";

    # Iterate over lines in the file to find the pattern
    while ( my $line = <$fh_in> ) { 
        if ( $line =~ m/Distance:/ ) { 
            # Found our result, print output
            chomp($line);
            $csv->say($out, [$c1, $line]);
            push @result, $line;
            # No need to continue if we know there is exactly one
            last; 
        }   
    }   
}
# Do something else with @result if needed ...
```

Comment: You rock!!!
Just wondering how I can acquire this kind of intuition and way of thinking. I'm really new to programming and it's been really frustrating... I've read some tutorials but it seems practice is the key. But when I try to work on a project I feel so inadequate. Any advice?

Comment: BTW, how can I grep two or more strings? Say, I want to grep Distance, Local angle, and Average angle. Don't think pipelines will work here.

Comment: @AvaXue Huh, thank you, but I disagree with the 'rock'-ing part :). Learning programming ... yes, lots of practice; yes, lots of reading; and, yes, it will take some time.  However, you can make progress quite rapidly and get to a comfortable place in not too long.  It seems to me that you are doing really well, trying various things out and not shying away from challenge.

Comment: @AvaXue   I'd emphasize one thing: make sure you work with proper resources so that you learn more than just how to write some code. By the problem subject I take it that your discipline isn't CS, so do as much as you can. It will take a little time but you can develop ability to write good software to do what you need. The more effort you put in the more of that you'll get :). If you can see that you will be doing programming for work regularly it is worth it.  Of course, don't let it distract you (too much) -- your chosen field needs your _full_ attention.

Comment: @AvaXue Multiple patterns: if you want to find a line that contains either, then that's _regular expressions_.  You can write it to match either one thing or another, so you catch a line with 'Distance' and the one with 'Local Angle ...' etc.  See for example [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).  Better yet, if you are going to use Perl, work through a book.  The "_Learning Perl_" used to be a classic, perfect one -- excellent, short and to the point, and brings you up to speed quickly.  I don't know new editions but I can imagine that it is still just as great.

Comment: @AvaXue  As for regex, I forgot the first one, [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).  Then there is the one I quoted already, [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), and then there would be a good book, for that and else.  Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

- Your data structure is a bit odd. Instead of naming files with meaningful names they are all named same and buried in subdirectories. Why are directories listed in .csv, are you supposed to skip some directories? Have you considered using a database?
- Move the sub out of your loop
- You do a find() on "$dir/$c1" where $c1 is something you can split() with spaces. This might be why you get repetitions. Try

  print "next finding in $dir/$c1\n"

before calling find() so you see what happens.

- I can't understand what you wanted to do, and reading the code makes me not wiser in this sense. Are you sure you know it yourself? Try first thinking *what* you want to do, instead of *how* you are doing it.

Would something like

```
grep -r Distance directory
```

do?

Comment: The subdirectories are named after the subunits and helices of different proteins and each one is unique. I have over 2500 subdirectories and I need to grep Distance from the txt file under roughly 2000 of them based on the csv file, which contains only those protein structures that I'm interested in. I couldn't think of another way to do it using Perl...

Comment: print "next finding in $dir/$c1\n" worked perfectly and gave me a complete, non-redundant list of all the subdirectories that I want.

Comment: Make a test copy of your clst1.csv, with only one line. How many items will what line have? How many times will while() loop run? How many times will foreach() loop? What will be values of $pair on each foreach. **Important: How will you use $pair?**